# Enterprise Library insert a object list in foreach. Does this make any deadlocks?

Tags: c#, foreach, enterprise-library, bulkinsert

I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library there is a situation with multiple rows insert, for that I am using foreach loop but I feel there is good way to do that

```
public int UddateSet
{    
    int rtn=0;

    foreach (Entities.Details list in day)    
    {    
         Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

         string sp = "spUpdateSet";    
         DbCommand dbcommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sp);

         db.AddInParameter(dbcommand, "@date", DbType.DateTime,date);
         db.AddInParameter(dbcommand, "@Id", DbType.Int32, list.Id);
         db.AddInParameter(dbcommand, "@Role", DbType.Int32, list.Role);

         rtn+= db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbcommand);
     }

     return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks are a tricky subject. The code you provided shouldn't cause any deadlocks if executed alone. Usually deadlocks happens when other processes have locks on the table and you are trying to insert data from another process.

Also you might want to just create one Connection and DbCommand and reuse it within the loop.Then when you are done make sure you call dispose (or using the using statement) on the DbCommand and Database objects.